# WebHostingHub Glyphs font ligatures won't work.

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I can't figure out why ligatures in the WebHostingHub Glyphs font won't work. I've used different programs and no matter what, it won't work. Someone who worked on its creation sent me here to ask. I'd appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Could you supply some code (presumably HTML and CSS at minimum since we're talking about webfonts, and anything else necessary) to reproduce the issue?